# What's git command to change remote filenames in a pattern?

Tags: git

I'd like to change names of files in git remote repository.
All the .txt files need to be renamed in a pattern.

(old) log.txt, readme.txt -->  (new) my-log.txt, my-readme.txt

What's git command to excute it?

Answer (score 1):

Try these bash commands:

```
for path in $(find . -name 'log.txt');do
    git mv ${path} ${path/log.txt/my-log.txt}
done

for path in $(find . -name 'readme.txt');do
    git mv ${path} ${path/readme.txt/my-readme.txt}
done

git commit
```

One-line commands in bash:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while read path;do bname=$(basename ${path});dname=$(dirname ${path});git mv "${path}" "${dname}/my-${bname}";done
```

I don't think a single command can do the job without scripting.

Comment: What I want is a single command that changes many files' name in a certain pattern.  Like, "Append prefix 'my-' to all the txt file names."

Comment: @berryjuniper Updated the answer. Not a real single command, but it takes only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't provide a general purpose file renaming facility, so there isn't a way to do this with just one command. You can use the `rename` utility (the Perl-based one called `rename` in Homebrew and Debian, not the util-linux one) to rename the commands using Perl expressions and then run `git add`.

For example, make sure your repository work tree is clean, then run:

```
$ rename 's/^/my-/' *.txt
$ git add .
```

If you want to do this recursively, you can do this instead:

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' | xargs rename 's/^/my-/'
$ git add .
```